# What type of event or tool should I use to model customer orders using pre-existing data?

Tags: anylogic

I am building a model where trucks leave main distributor to make deliveries to several customers along a route before returning back to the distributor when it is empty. I have been given pre-existing data in the form of a CSV of the exact location of all of the orders, the order weight, and how many orders there were at that location -- therefore, it's not a stochastic process that I'm modeling. My goal is to see how many deliveries the truck can make within 300 miles and a 20-hour round trip driving time, with the truck's total weight being decremented by the order weight at each stop. The initial truck capacity was 40,000 pounds.

Currently, I've created a standard "order" event, though I'm concerned my code is not correctly doing what I want it to. My order trigger type is "Timeout," mode is "cyclic," the first occurrence is 0.999 days, and the recurrence time is every 1 days. Below is my code on the "Action" module:

```
for( Truck truck: main.trucks){
    double freeCapacity = truck.truckMaxCapacity - truck.truckCapacity;
    if( distanceTo(truck, MILE) < 300 && totalWeight < freeCapacity && findFirst(main.trucks, tr->tr.customers.contains(this)) == null){
        truck.customers.add(this);
        truck.truckCapacity += totalWeight;
    }
}
```

Since I'm not passing in the direct parameters of the orders in my code, I'm concerned the code I've written so far is generating orders rather than using what I already have. I have the order identification number, weight, and location all loaded in from a database within my "Customer" agent, which is also where the "order" event is located.

I'm new to StackOverflow, so thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Where is the "totalWeight" variable coming from? Is it a property of Customer? Not really clear but you currently are not creating any orders. Instead, every day your customers are adding workload to those trucks. But not really linked to any orders...

Comment: Yes, totalWeight is a property of customer, which exists to count the remaining weight on the truck after an order is delivered. Hmm, I think I see the problem -- do you know a way I might go about fixing it?

Comment: Change your model structure. Check out the example model on supply chain deliveries, they have truck, customer and order agents set up properly

Comment: I see. Do you mean the "product delivery" model? I actually based my initial model off of that one using the same model structure, but ended up hitting a wall with it. I think it was because that model generates demand with a stochastic event called generateDemand, which wasn't applicable to what I was trying to do. I'm trying to load in exact order data to use for the truck deliveries.

Comment: fine, but still use the architecture where orders are agents themselves ;-)

Comment: Okay, I created an "Order" agent, but I'm having some trouble connecting it to the infrastructure of my model. I'm not sure how to connect the order data into the agent itself, and the code I added to my "order" event which creates the orders keeps throwing me a "The constructor Order(customer) is undefined" error.